# Smoothly Parametrized basis of $V\otimes V$

Tags: tensor-products

$\{(\cos t,\sin t),(-\sin t,\cos t)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$.

Is it also a basis of $\mathbb{R}\otimes \mathbb{R}$?

If not, what's an easy way to construct a non-trivial basis of $V\otimes V$?

Comment: A basis is relative to the field of scalars.  Direct sum $\oplus$ is differently constructed from tensor product $\otimes$.

Comment: I assume that you mean, for any $t \in \mathbb R$, $\{(\cos t, \sin t),(-\sin t, \cos t)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$. Furthermore, what are your conditions for non-trivial basis?

Comment: The title includes the phrase "smoothly parameterized basis" that does not appear in the Question's body.  I'm not sure in what sense a basis for a vector space is smoothly parameterized.  Possibly this is connected with the notion of "non-trivial basis" mentioned in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to a real field of scalars, $\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}$ is just one dimensional (scalar multiples can pass from one side to the other), while $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ is two dimensional.

More generally a basis for tensor product $V \otimes W$ of two vectors spaces over field $\mathbb{F}$ can be taken to be tensor products of basis elements of $V$ with basis elements of $W$.  This means in the finite dimensional case that:

$$ \text{dim}(V\otimes W) = \text{dim}(V) \text{ dim}(W) $$